# What is the difference between these two lines of code in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, filter

In my dataset, this dplyr lines drops 3 rows

```
t <- filter(df, !str_detect(df.row1, "text"))
```

But this line drops 13 rows

```
t <- subset(df, !(grepl("text", df.row1)))
```

I feel like I'm missing some subtle logical difference between how you negate?

I've changed the ! symbol to put before filter command, and that has not worked.

Comment: Hi T Miller! Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would be helpful to see the actual dataframe. Would you be able to run `dput(df)` and add the results to your question? Thanks!

Comment: Can you share an example of any `df.row1` values which are filtered differently by your code?

Comment: Is the difference all instances where `df$df.row1` is `NA`?

Comment: @Darren it's not `filter` but `grepl("text", NA)` is FALSE whereas for `str_detect` it's NA.

Comment: @Hugh yes the problem results from the difference between `grepl` and `str_detect`, not from `filter` or `subset`.

Comment: @Darren Thumbs up on that answer. Good to keep in mind.